# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar esta matriz de menor a mayor?

Tags: python, matriz

He estado buscando varias alternativas pero no consigo ordenar la matriz de menos a mayor sin sort().¿Cómo puedo detectar?

```
serie = [4,3,2,1,6,8,7]

for i in serie:
    if i > 0:
        i = i - 1
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías recorrer la lista con 2 ciclos `for` uno para recorrer todos los valores y otro para recorrer desde la posición siguiente de la iteración actual hasta el final, comparar los números y en caso de que sea mayor intercambiarlos

```
serie = [4,3,2,1,6,8,7]

for i in range(len(serie)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(serie)):
        if serie[i] > serie[j]:
            serie[i], serie[j] = serie[j], serie[i]

print(serie)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Otra opción sería crear una nueva lista, comparar cada valor de la serie con el primer valor, en caso de encontrar uno menor obtenerlo, si no hay uno menor entonces el menor sería el primer elemento, ese elemento eliminarlo de la serie original y agregarlo con `append` a la nueva lista. Al terminar en la lista original habrá 0 elementos y en la nueva lista tendrás todos los elementos ordenados

```
serie = [4,3,2,1,6,8,7]
nueva_lista = []

while serie:
    minimo = serie[0]
    for x in serie: 
        if x < minimo:
            minimo = x
    nueva_lista.append(minimo)
    serie.remove(minimo)    

print(nueva_lista)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: ¿por qué hacerlo "a mano" si ya existen métodos nativos para ordenar listas?

Comment: Porque así era la pregunta del OP, al mencionar que no puede utilizar el método `sort()` es evidente que no puede utilizar métodos de ordenamiento

Comment: ah no vi que no podia utilizar `sort`